# Jquery loop runs twice on in bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I am generating contents of a bootstrap modal via ajax. When data loads into it, i want to loop through each of the "select" (which are dynamic in number) in that modal and alert its name and selected value but it always alert me twice, first time it alerts all the default selected values and then it alerts the one i selected.
My dynamic bootstrap content generation code is following

```
 $(document).on('click','.quick_view',function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 var serverBaseUrl = '<?php echo base_url();?>';
 $(".modal-body").html('');
 $("#qv").modal('show');

 $.post(
   serverBaseUrl+'Ajax/productQuickView.php',
   {
     id:$(this).attr('data-id')    
   },
   function(html_response){
     $(".modal-body").html(html_response);
     return false;
   }

  );// post
 }); // Document dot on click quick view
```

My Jquery loop runs twice when some one click a button with id of "alertselected" in modal and its code is

```
$(document).on('click','#alertselected',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var serverBaseUrl = '<?php echo base_url();?>';
  $('select').each(function() {    
    var selectedOption = $(this).find('option:selected');
    alert('Value: ' + selectedOption.val() + ' Text: ' + selectedOption.text());
  }); //select dot each

}); // Document dot on click quick view
```

Comment: You must have more than one select box present on the page when it gets to `$('select').each(function()` maybe even in a totally different area. You might try making the selector in  `$('select')` more specific like  `$('.modal-body select')` so you aren't grabbing every select on the page

Comment: @DelightedD0D Actually it alerts me all those "selects" in modal correctly but the problem is that, it alerts twice. for example i have 3 selects in that modal with default selected text as "select an option" . it first alerts "select an option" 3 times then it alerts those values which i selected from those drop downs.

Comment: Are you using any sort of select plugin that might be cloning the selectboxes and hiding the originals?

Comment: No, i am grabbing all the data including the data for selects from ajax call. All those selects are dynamic in nature.

Comment: Also, you're calling `$(".modal-body").html(html_response);` are you *sure* that you do not have more than one modal? if you do, that code will add your html to all of them

Comment: Yes, i am sure, this is the only modal i have.

Comment: And you dont have the class `.modal-body` on some other element by mistake?

Comment: If not, can you please inspect the rendered page in the dev tools and post the rendered html, that is the html after the ajax runs?

Comment: OMG, Thank you, thanks alot. I missed one, i had another ".modal-body". Got it right now changed that to populate via an id.

Comment: No, worries. That's a mistake we've all made  :)

Answer (score 1):

You can either use `off` or `unbind` to first `off/unbind` the event, then attach the event

```
$(document).off('click').on('click','#alertselected',function(e){ 
  ...//Rest of code
})
```

Comment: This didn't work on my side as i tried this one. The problem was that there was another ".modal-body" which made loop run twice, once for default values and once for selected values. Thanks to @DelightedD0D